# Телеграм бот Scala

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, scala

Библиотека telegrambot4s. Ничего не помогает не приходит запрос. Пробовал VPN и прокси ничего не помогает

```
import info.mukel.telegrambot4s.api._
import info.mukel.telegrambot4s.methods._
import info.mukel.telegrambot4s.models._



object EchoBot extends TelegramBot with Polling {
  override def token: String = "###"
  override def receiveMessage(msg: Message): Unit = {
    for (text <- msg.text) {
      println(text)
      request(SendMessage(msg.source, text.reverse))
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Я взял твой код, подставил токен от своего бота, запустил с помощью `EchoBot.run()`. Пока скала-программа запущена - написал боту через сам телеграм - сообщения появились в консоли скалы.

Comment: @EnverOsmanov Я залил на американский сервак. Его мониторю. Только так помогло